# While traversing over linked list not changes head reference

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am a new learner and learning about linked list and java both.

I already know the concept that when two references point to same object then changing the fields value of one reference also changes the other reference fields value. Let's suppose we have below class:-

```
 public class Test {

    int a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t=new Test();

        t.a=15;
        System.out.println("a="+t.a); //will print a=15

        Test temp=t;
        temp.a=20;

        System.out.println("a="+t.a); //will print a=20

    }
}
```

This is what we called shallow copying changing the object value through one reference will update the value of all the references pointing to that object.

Similarly I am traversing over a linked list through below code by taking temporary reference of `head` in `currNode`.

```
public static void printList(LinkedList list) { 
        Node currNode = list.head; 

        while (currNode != null) { 
            System.out.print(currNode.data + " "); 

            currNode = currNode.next; 
        } 
    }
```

Why `currNode = currNode.next;` is not updating the value of `head` to `null` when it reaches at the end of the linked list as we are performing  ?

Comment: the `currNode = currNode.next;` statement is changing the value of currNode, and doesn't make any change to the list. It doesn't change any attribute of any object. 
So it is not expected to change the list.head value.

Comment: @Alain-MichelChomnoueN but currNode and head both pointing to the same object. Isn't it? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: They point to the same object until you execute `currNode = currNode.next;`. After that statement, currNode will point to the value of head.next.

Answer (score 0):

in the first example (`class Test`) you have two references for the same object any change in the first will effect the other reference.
the same in the second example if you change the data of the head at the first iteration it will change the data of the `currtNode` because both references points to the same object.
but the statement `currNode = currNode.next;` changes the the value of the `currNode` to points to the next node, so after the first iteration the two references `head` and `currNode` don't points at the same object, because that at the end of the function the `head!=null`